# Field $valid state is not updating after $setValidity(True)

Tags: validation, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using `ui-validate` for my validation rules.

```
<input  ng-model=raw.expression 
        name="expression" 
        type="text"
        required
        ui-validate="{serversidevalid : 'validate_serverside($value)'}">
```

The validation is executed server side, the short version ... in the controller

```
$scope.validate_serverside = function(expression) {

  someValidationFactory
   .validate(expression)
   .then(function(server_error_message) { 

      var validity = true, 
          error_message = false, 
          input = $scope.my_form['expression'];

      if (server_error_message !== undefined) {
        validity = false;
        error_message = server_error_message;
      }

      input.$setValidity('serversidevalid',validity);
      input.$error.serversidevalid = error_message;

  });
```

Now, after this function is executed with a valid expression - **The form's status is valid, The $error key and message are as exepected but the field's $valid / $invalid remains invalid.**

How is it possible for the entire form to become valid but the field to remain invalid ?

I tried wrapping the two last statements with `$scope.$apply` or explicitly trigger `$scope.$digest()` but the it throws an "digest already in progress". I tried wrapping the thing with `$timeout` to execute after the digest is done - same undesired result.

appreciate some guidance here.

Answer (score 1):

So I came across this discussion on [github](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/issues/257) and after a quick look at the code I relaized that as of the last couple of month `ui-validate` support server side validation via promises.

So I dropped the external manipulation of `$setValidity` and changed my validation as follows

```
$scope.validate_serverside = function(expression) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  someValidationFactory
   .validate(expression)
   .then(function(server_error_message) { 

      if (server_error_message !== undefined)
         deferred.reject(false)
      else 
         deferred.resolve(true)
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```